# fenster error showing java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: audio

Tags: android

there are showing error in xml like below.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: audio   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:602)   at com.malmstein.fenster.seekbar.VolumeSeekBar.initialise(VolumeSeekBar.java:78)   at com.malmstein.fenster.controller.MediaFensterPlayerController.initControllerView(MediaFensterPlayerController.java:205)   at com.malmstein.fenster.controller.MediaFensterPlayerController.onFinishInflate(MediaFensterPlayerController.java:174)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:867)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) Copy stack to clipboard  Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

i have added build.gradle(module app)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.malmstein:fenster:0.0.2'
}
```

i have added in build.gradle(project: name)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.malmstein:fenster:0.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

how to solve this error please

Comment: Please post the related classes where you have used fenster

Comment: dear the error showing while i open xml preview. otherwise its working well.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild ?

Comment: yes.,.,.,.,., infact i followed the way they showed in github

Comment: But is it interfering in your execution ?

Comment: no.its working fine only while i am trying to show xml preview from android studio then showing the error

Comment: So, I guess you don't need to worry about it

Comment: ok.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.